# g++ the order of static library matters?

Tags: c++, makefile, g++

I have been struggling all day for this problem. I use some libraries in my project and I always got some compilation errors complaining that `undefined reference`.

The relevant files are as follows:

```
encode.cc//the main file
url_codec.h//the header of the libraries, got some function definition in it
libimageenc.a
libmbpicenc.a
liburlaes.a
liburldecode.a
```

The makefile is like:

```
cflags = -Wall -O2 -fPIC

libpath=./libs/
libs+=$(libpath)liburlaes.a
libs+=$(libpath)liburldecode.a $(libpath)libimageenc.a $(libpath)libmbpicenc.a

cxx  = g++
bin  = encode

all: $(bin)

srcs = $(shell ls *.cc *.cpp)
objs = $(srcs:%.cc=%.o)

$(bin):${objs}
    $(cxx) $(cflags) $(inc) -o $@ ${objs} ${libs}

$(objs):%.o:%.cc
    $(cxx) $(cflags) $(inc) -c -o $@ $<

clean:
    rm -f *.o
    rm -f *.bak
    rm -f $(bin)
```

The g++ compiler complains that:

```
g++ -Wall -O2 -fPIC  -o encode encode.o ./libs/liburlaes.a ./libs/liburldecode.a ./libs/libimageenc.a ./libs/libmbpicenc.a
./libs/liburldecode.a(url_codec.o): In function `url_codec::offpic_url_decode_func(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, unsigned int&, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >&, int&)':
url_codec.cc:(.text+0x18da): undefined reference to `uuid_unparse'
./libs/liburldecode.a(crypto_aes.o): In function `encode_aes':
crypto_aes.cc:(.text+0x4e): undefined reference to `AES_cbc_encrypt'
./libs/liburldecode.a(crypto_aes.o): In function `decode_aes':
crypto_aes.cc:(.text+0xae): undefined reference to `AES_cbc_encrypt'
./libs/liburldecode.a(crypto_aes.o): In function `init_aes_encrypt_key':
crypto_aes.cc:(.text+0xf3): undefined reference to `AES_set_encrypt_key'
./libs/liburldecode.a(crypto_aes.o): In function `init_aes_decrypt_key':
crypto_aes.cc:(.text+0x143): undefined reference to `AES_set_decrypt_key'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

But all these function are well defined in liburlaes.a as shown by `nm -C`

```
    nm -C liburlaes.a | grep -i 'aes'
    decode_byaes.o:
         U AES_cbc_encrypt
         U AES_set_decrypt_key
         U AES_set_encrypt_key
00000060 T decode_byaes
00000000 T encode_byaes
00000110 T init_byaes_decrypt_key
000000c0 T init_byaes_encrypt_key
         U decode_byaes
         U encode_byaes
         U init_byaes_decrypt_key
         U init_byaes_encrypt_key
```

Things won't get better by moving the `liburlaes.a` to the end of `libs`, the output is exactly as above. And move `libimageenc` backward will make it worse, with more symbols claimed undefined:

```
libs+=$(libpath)liburldecode.a $(libpath)libimageenc.a $(libpath)libmbpicenc.a
libs+=$(libpath)liburlaes.a
```

So, how can I fix this?

**UPDATES**

I tried to put the `liburlaes.a` in both side, but it doesn't work, I wrap the libaray with '**' to emphasize :

```
g++ -Wall -O2 -fPIC  -o encode encode.o **./libs/liburlaes.a** ./libs/liburldecode.a ./libs/libimageenc.a ./libs/libmbpicenc.a **./libs/liburlaes.a**
./libs/liburldecode.a(url_codec.o): In function `url_codec::offpic_url_decode_func(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, unsigned int&, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >&, int&)':
url_codec.cc:(.text+0x18da): undefined reference to `uuid_unparse'
./libs/liburldecode.a(crypto_aes.o): In function `encode_aes':
crypto_aes.cc:(.text+0x4e): undefined reference to `AES_cbc_encrypt'
./libs/liburldecode.a(crypto_aes.o): In function `decode_aes':
crypto_aes.cc:(.text+0xae): undefined reference to `AES_cbc_encrypt'
./libs/liburldecode.a(crypto_aes.o): In function `init_aes_encrypt_key':
crypto_aes.cc:(.text+0xf3): undefined reference to `AES_set_encrypt_key'
./libs/liburldecode.a(crypto_aes.o): In function `init_aes_decrypt_key':
crypto_aes.cc:(.text+0x143): undefined reference to `AES_set_decrypt_key'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [encode] Error 1
```

Comment: You just need to put your libraries in the correct order. If you have circular dependencies then you may need to specify a library twice.

Comment: The makefile has some general issues: Use the standard identifiers for variables, not your own, slightly different ones – it will mess with automatic rules (`CXX` not `cxx`, `CXXFLAGS`, not `cflags`). Also, your `objs` variable will contain `*.cpp` names because you fail to replace that extension. Path variables shouldn’t end on `/`. The `$(objs)` rule contains a syntax error, I think. And finally, use a consistent variable access style – either `$(…)` or `${…}`, not both.

Comment: @KonradRudolph ... I am a fresher in Linux programming. I never used that before, with my lovely IDE. Please have a look at the complains if you are familiar with this.

Comment: @zoujyjs Apologies, that was uncalled for. I added some specifics to my comment.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Linker order - GCC](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/45135/linker-order-gcc)

Comment: @jogojapan This is a specific question focus more on the complains of the g++ compiler. The title is a little unspecific, so might looks like duplicated.

Comment: I suggested the duplicate partly because you had already accepted Mats Petersson's answer. That answer is good, but it's also very general. If that answer is what you were looking for, then what is the specific difference between your question and the other one? (Note that the other one is also about GCC.)

Comment: @jogojapan Thank you for your suggestion. I will take more attention to avoid this situation. And I has a comment on that answer, giving the reason for the acception.

Comment: Right -- that comment came in after I had voted to put the question on hold. Anyway, I don't think it will be put on hold (there are only 2 votes so far), but if it is and you think it should be re-opened, just send me another comment, I will vote to reopen it in that case.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, the order of libraries definitely matter. You need to put whatever uses the library first, then the library.

I have had cases where library A depends on something in library B, and library B needs something in library A, so you then need to put library A twice in the list.

The way the linker works is that it processes the object files, then reads the libraries to resolve the symbols not present in the object files. If the library has the object "files" to solve the dependency, then those parts are included. It then goes on to the next library. It doesn't "remember" what it has seen in the previous libraries.

Comment: @PaulR This is some libraries that I don't really know the dependency. But just have a look at the complain, the `liburldecode.a` use some functions which are defined in `liburlaes.a`. Nothing else is wrong by now, How can I fix this problem first, just put the `liburlaes.a` behind doesn't work!

Comment: Yes, I put the `liburlaes.a` in both side, output is exatly! See my updates.

Comment: And the liburlaes definitely contains the functions you need? It's not a "standard" library from what I can tell, so it's impossible for me to say.

Comment: Find out that other libraries are missing. For this is a specific problem, the missing libraries are not listed here. And the answer is more valuable than the question itself.

Answer (score 0):

How about this，just put liburlaes.a right behind the liburldecode.a.

```
 g++ -Wall -O2 -fPIC  -o encode encode.o  ./libs/liburldecode.a **./libs/liburlaes.a **./libs/libimageenc.a ./libs/libmbpicenc.a
```